# Do I use "I" and "I have" for skills I gained and still possess?

Tags: tense, perfect-aspect

When discussing skills I gained from a past job but still possess, do I use "I" or "I have?"

> In my work as a Communication Specialist, **I**/**I have** developed communication and leadership skills.

> As the Communication Intern, **I**/**I have** honed my writing and editing skills.

Comment: Take your pick. Using the perfect tense simply puts the emphasis on the process concerned. As I young person, you would probably use the perfect tense. An older person , reflecting, would probably use the simple past.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are still developing those skills, or not.

For the skills you mention, I expect they cross over differing work areas (you would do them in many jobs).

So if you are still developing those skills somehow, then use "I have..."

But if not, then:

> I developed a new, improved pizza oven."

as an activity that has completely ended.